# Passing another argument in the KeyRelease function Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to check the input for each button release but the value I want to compare the input to is constantly changing. What can I do to pass another argument in the "check" function to fix it?

```py
def check(event:tkinter.Event=None, ans #<== Won't work) -> None:
    if Text.get("0.0", "end").strip() == str(ans):
        check_val = True

while True:
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Math")
    master.geometry('400x400')

    eq = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
    ans = calc(eq) 
    Label(master=master,text=f"score: {score}").grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)
    Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0,column=0 ,sticky=W)

    inputtxt = tkinter.Text(master=master,height = 5, width = 20)
    inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>",check)
    inputtxt.grid()
        
    if check_val:
        score += 10
        q_num += 1

        if score % 100 == 0:
            current_stage += 1

    else:
        inputtxt.grid()
        inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

    user_input = ""
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda even: check(event, ans))`. Also please look at event driven programming tutorials. Right now it doesn't look like you understand how event driven programming works.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem (as stated in a comment on the question by [TheLizzard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11106801/thelizzard)) is using the `lambda` statement to pass additional arguments to `check()` when you bind it to `"<KeyRelease>"`.

Notice how you run *all* the code in a `while` loop: unless you want your window to keep popping up again and again, it's unnecesary, as `root.mainloop()` runs the loop for you. Variables only need to be defined once, unless you're changing them. So you can remove the `while` loop.

Also, you reference `tkinter` attributes with and without "tkinter" in front, like `tkinter.Text` and `Label`. As both `Label` and `Text` are part of the `tkinter` module, this makes it so that you have to use both `import tkinter` *and* `from tkinter import *`. Wildcard imports (using `from module import *` )are generally discouraged. Just `import tkinter`, and use "tkinter" in front of the `tkinter` attributes; in your case, `tkinter.Label` and `tkinter.Tk` instead of `Label` and `Tk`.

Here is what your code would look like with these changes made:

```
import tkinter

def check(ans, text, event=None):
    if text.get("0.0", "end").strip() == str(ans):
        check_val = True

    if check_val:
        score += 10
        q_num += 1

        if score % 100 == 0:
            current_stage += 1

    else:
        inputtxt.grid()
        inputtxt.delete(1.0,END)

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("Math")
master.geometry('400x400')

eq = generate_equation(stage=current_stage)
ans = calc(eq) 
tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"score: {score}").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W)
tkinter.Label(master=master, text=f"{q_num}: {eq}").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

inputtxt = tkinter.Text(master=master, height=5, width=20)
inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>", lambda event, ans=ans, text=inputtxt: check(ans, text))
inputtxt.grid()

user_input = ""
master.mainloop()
```

Note how I also put the `if check_val...` code inside the `check()` function. I'm assuming that you want to check the value repeatedly. If not, you can just move the code back to where it was.

Another change: I pass `inputtext` as an argument to `check()` in the line `inputtxt.bind("<KeyRelease>"...`. This is because I noticed you were trying to get the text in a `Text` widget that didn't exist.